# Manually put files to Android emulator SD card

Tags: android, emulation, mount, sd-card

I'm just having trouble with getting my emulator SD card work...
I created a new AVD device with a new SD card.

So how to put data onto it? I found the "correct" file to be mounted on Daemon tools, but is corrupt or simply not readable...

It would be great if you have any idea :)

Comment: If you are trying to do it via code you can write to `/sdcard/`

Answer (score 131, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse you can move files to and from the SD Card through the Android Perspective (it is called DDMS in Eclipse). Just select the Emulator in the left part of the screen and then choose the File Explorer tab. Above the list with your files should be two symbols, one with an arrow pointing at a phone, clicking this will allow you to choose a file to move to phone memory.

Comment: hi, thanks, that seems to work, but how can I add a whole directory with subdirectories?

Comment: you can also run ddms as a standalone application if you have the android SDK installed.  It's at $ANDROID_SDK_PATH/tools/ddms

Comment: When I ran ddms from the Android SDK Path, The file explorer was not there as a tab. But it was there in the menu. Device -> File Explorer

Comment: is there a way to delete a file/folder from the DDMS perspective?

Comment: Just to add. It must be running to show in the DDMS Devices list.

Comment: Hello1 I just did that - uploaded files to simulator, but I have a little problem. When I try to get Environment.getExternalStorageState(); all is OK, but I can't get list of files from that program folder. On device it is working, but on simulator fails. Did you have such problem? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 107):

Use the adb tool that comes with the SDK.

```
adb push myDirectory /sdcard/targetDir
```

If you only specify `/sdcard/` (with the trailing slash) as destination, then the CONTENTS of myDirectory will end up in the root of /sdcard.

Comment: @olafure: Can a file be pushed to the android's sd card, not directory.

Comment: @user1139023 sure, just append a '/' after the directory name, like:
`adb push yourfile.ext /sdcard/`
that would put yourfile.ext in the root of /sdcard

Comment: If you are using Eclipse's File Explorer and getting "read only file system" errors, first run from cmdline: adb remount

Comment: Yeah this is by far the most simple way.

Answer (score 49):

In Android Studio, open the Device Manager:
  **Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor**

In Eclipse open the Device Manager:
[image]

In the device manager you can add files to the SD Card here:
[image]

Comment: thanks.. but is throwing error in eclipse console saying--"Failed to push selection: Read-only file system"

Comment: @Charlie You need to check the permission , because your file system can not be write anything as error message shows

Comment: perfect ! Thanks

Comment: I wasn't able to push any file or folder to the `mnt/sdcard` dir, I had to use `storage/12EA-2A1E` instead. Probably that folder name is auto-generated for each AVD.

Answer (score 41):

One easy way is to drag and drop. It will copy files to /sdcard/Download. You can copy whole folders or multiple files. Make sure that "Enable Clipboard Sharing" is enabled. (under ...->Settings)[image]

Comment: Ënable clip board sharing is not there now :/

Comment: damn! this worked like a charm!! thank you so much!!

Comment: @UmerAsif It is for me on my two systems. Are you sure?

Comment: This worked for me as well, but just to clarify a bit, the settings he's referring to is what's shown in the screenshot — it's the settings accessed at the bottom of the floating toolbar, not from Settings within the emulator. Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 3):

I am using Android Studio 3.3.

Go to **View -> Tools Window -> Device File Explorer**. Or you can find it on the Bottom Right corner of the Android Studio.

If the Emulator is running, the Device File Explorer will display the File structure on Emulator Storage.

Here you can right click on a Folder and select "Upload" to place the file

[image]

Comment: Hi , with this technique also it shows file permission denied when android code tries to access fie present at this location.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2019 (Xamarin):

1. Click on the Device Monitor (DDMS) button.

[image]

2. Go to the File Explorer tab and click the button with a phone and a right-pointing arrow on top of it.

[image]