# Android- SDCard

Tags: android, sd-card

I am currently working on Windows with android 2.2. I am trying to create an SDCard for the Emulator. I have created Sdcard.iso. I am trying to pull songs and videos into it. But I do no how to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808632/manually-put-files-to-android-emulator-sd-card

Comment: .iso? - I thought sd-card images end on .img!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [SD Card Emulation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#sdcard) section on the Android developer site, specifically under the heading "Copying files to a disk image".

[Here's](http://blog.jayway.com/2009/04/22/working-with-sd-cards-in-the-android-emulator/) an additional blog post (slightly older, not 2.2) with some information on adding content.

Answer (score 0):

If you use eclipse you can also use the android file browser view to browse and copy files to the sdcard of a running emulator instance. Just make sure you select the emulator device in the android devices view first.

Answer (score 0):

From Eclipse this is the way to do it,
               -> Launch your emulator with -sdcard  set in Run Configuration - Target - Additional Emulator Command Line Options
               -> Once the emulator is launched go to Windows->Open Perspective->DDMS
               -> Select the emulator from Devices window, and go to File Explorer in the right
               -> Browse to mnt>sdcard
               -> Now you can push and pull files to the sdcard, see top right there are two icons to push and pull content.

Hope this helps :)