# Path to file in Android Eclipse project

Tags: android

I need to use map rendering library in my android project. I want to use code found in [mapsforge website](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/).

First, I must set the map I want to use. Method to do that is `setMapFile(String newMapFile)` from [`MapView`](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/source/browse/trunk/mapsforge/src/org/mapsforge/android/maps/MapView.java#) class. I tried to place map file in `assets` and `res/raw` folder in Eclipse project and then give path to it, but it doesn't work for me.

Could anyone tell me how to correctly deliver path with map to this map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to place the map files on the SD card and access them as described in [GettingStartedMapView](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/wiki/GettingStartedMapView).

One of the mapsforge developers answers [a similar question on `mapsforge-dev` Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mapsforge-dev/JNAUum1K8lU) explaining why **map files can not be placed inside the app** (i.e. in the `assets` or `res` folder):

> [...] The problem is, that a
>   `java.io.RandomAccessFile` instance is needed in order to read the map
>   data from a binary map file. Just having an `InputStream` is not enough,
>   as it doesn't have a `seek()` method. Calling `skip(n)` is not the same.
>   In worst case all n bytes will be read, which is not an option for
>   huge map files.
>
> Unfortunately, Android does not offer seekable file access on
>   resources. That is due to the way all resource files are packaged and
>   compressed into one `.apk` file. A quick Google search reveals that many
>   other people are having the same problem. One work around may be to
>   copy the file to the SD card or internal phone filesystem when your
>   application is started for the first time. See:
>   http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/59b6bf70ca6d2081
>
> But depending on the file size, this copying process may take a longer
>   time. Having map files bundled with your application will also
>   increase the size of your APK file a lot. Another disadvantage is that
>   the map file can no longer be updated separately or copied to other
>   devices.

Comment: Thanks for replay! So it is impossible to use that code in emulator? I wanted firstly test library on emulator and after that use mobile. If it is impossible the only way to test code will be after changes debuging in android bridge?

Comment: The Android emulator can emulate an SD card as well, so it's perfectly possible to test this on the emulator. You can use the Android Eclipse plugin to "upload" a file to the emulator's SD card: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808632/manually-put-files-to-android-emulator-sd-card/2808935#2808935