# Read a string from my file system (C:\) when running an android application

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to read a text file (Using BufferedReader and FileReader) from my file sytem on my android application and I'm getting "FileNotFound" Exception (I do have permissions).
Is it because my android application cannot access my file system ?
What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should show the code obviously.

But assuming that you are reading from `c:\`: a virtual device does not know about anything called `c:\`. You should read a file from your virtual device.

Comment: I assumed that is the problem. But how can I put a file on my virtual device ?

Comment: You can find this out easily, for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808632/manually-put-files-to-android-emulator-sd-card