# Auto-populate android inbox

Tags: android, android-emulator, sms, generator

I am working on an android app to analyze a users message history.

One major issue is that i need a bank of messages to work with, ideally over a long period of time.

I have found how to send messages to the emulator via telnet but this is A. slow and B. messages are time stamped on arrival.

I would like suggestions on how to programmatically generate a pseudo-random inbox of say, 300 messages (content doesn't matter at this point, but i need a range of times and dates).

Update: As an idea, would it be possible to somehow load my phones (1.5 android) message history to the emulator?

Comment: Do you really need real messages? You can easily to generate base and work with it.

Comment: no they dont need to be real at all. all i need is a pile of messages with a range of dates and times.

Comment: Can you provide your code of getting smses?

Comment: out of the house currently, but i will a later tonight.

Comment: Do you want to sync the Messages from default to your app...?? You need to use ContentProvder to fetch the messages details

Comment: Here is a simple message reader that prints the number and body to the log.

Comment: What i need is some thing to GENERATE messages to later be readed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to track and analyse the message history in your app, you can easily use a content provider for accessing SMS messages. But it's not documented in the public SDK.

If you use `ContentResolver.query()` with a Uri of `content://sms` you should be able to access these messages on 1.5(ECLAIR) and later version.

Please go through the link for details how to do all that:[Referal for Content Provider](http://mobdev.olin.edu/mobdevwiki/FrontPage/Tutorials/SMS%20Messaging)

Also before beginning on Content Provider, please visit and understand the Android Developer Blog.
Once: [Android Developer Blog Warns to do that..](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html)

Answer (score 1):

Install Android Market on your emulator (see here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21862/how-to-enable-the-android-market-in-the-google-android-emulator/)

Install an SMS backup app such as [SMS Backup And Restore](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore&hl=en) on both your real device and emulator, use it to back up messages from your real device to a file, transfer the file to desktop (email, bluetooth or whatever), put it on your emulator's virtual SD card (see: [Manually put files to Android emulator SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808632/manually-put-files-to-android-emulator-sd-card)), use the same app to restore your messages on the emulator.

Also, to manually put stuff into the db (/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db), try using this tool: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/ or just write a script using sqlite3 to stuff teh db with fake data, here's another relevant thread on accessing the db: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11619/android-read-recent-sms-messages-from-command-line

Answer (score 1):

the sms db is stored at /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db . Copy this from your phone onto the sdk. Or you could populate the db once and take a backup and restore it everytime.