# Move an entire folder from windows to Android emulator

Tags: android, adb, ddms

Is it possible to move an entire folder as is from windows to an android emulator? - I am sure the answer to this exists somewhere but I am not able to find it. I can move one file at a time either via adb command line or via ddms but neither gives me the option to move entire folder with multiple folders and files inside and when I try to it gives me this error

```
C:\>adb push C:\Users\peng-lp-10\Desktop\ABC\ /mnt/sdcard/ABC/
cannot stat 'C:\Users\peng-lp-10\Desktop\ABC\': No such file or direct
ory
```

even if the folder exists.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808632/manually-put-files-to-android-emulator-sd-card),[furikuretsu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402534/furikuretsu) says:

> you can simply ***drag*** any sets of ***files*** and ***folders*** to ***File Explorer*** (a window in DDMS perspective). No
>   need of using arrow icons.

It works fine.