# How can an Android app folder be backed up and restored on an emulator

Tags: android, backup, directory, emulation, restore

Is there a way to back up an Android app folder from an emulator to a computer, then restore it to another emulator?

For example, Android emulator A has an app called Foo, therefore it has the following folder with many sub-folders and numerous files:
/data/data/com.my.foo

I would like to back up this folder, then restore it to emulator B.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In eclipse:**

DDMS perspective -> select emulator in devices tab -> File Explorer on the right hand side

Download to PC and revert the process on the other emulator.

---

**Pushing via adb:**

It seems that the eclipse tools does not support putting folders on to device.

pushing from adb commandline: adb root push com.my.foo /data/data/com.my.foo/

Comment: I can pull the folder in the way you described, but I cannot figure out how to push a folder to the emulator. Could you offer a tip on this?

Comment: If you hold your mouse over File Explorer and move to your right, you will see two icons with purple/pink'ish arrows. Those are pull/push, respectively. I would assume that to work, otherwise please let me know.

Comment: in case it does not, pushing from adb commandline: adb push com.my.foo /data/data/com.my.foo/

Comment: I see the two icons which I use frequently for individual files.  The pull can handle folders, but the push does not seem to be able to handle folders.

Comment: Try the commandline i added im last comments. You might have to do adb - e shell then su and then the above command without adb

Comment: Thanks a lot for your persistent help. Actually, I have been trying to figure out how to use the command to to avail. I got an error described in the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497660/move-an-entire-folder-from-windows-to-android-emulator  According to the answer, one can drag and drop a folder to the emulator, but I cannot.  I do not know if anything is wrong with my setup.

Comment: Hallelujah! The command line works. Thanks a lot!  Could you add the command line to your answer so that I can mark it?

Comment: Nice! :)  did you need to do su, or was the current answer enough?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38227/discussion-between-hong-and-cyrixmorten)