# android ecelipse virtual devices

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, virtual-machine

i have found many questions about how to send a file to a virtual device.. it is clear and simple now ..(using DDMS-> file explorer or just file explorer) but in fact i am looking to send a folder that contains hundreds of files to the Sdcard of the virtual device.. 
using the file explorer you can push a file.. or create a new folder.. is there any chance to push a folder or paste it on the Sdcard.. if not is there any way to push file into specific folder in the sdcard..
i tried to find an answer on the internet.. but i didn't find any thing ..
thanks 4 your help..

Comment: Go to this:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808632/manually-put-files-to-android-emulator-sd-card/2808935#2808935](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808632/manually-put-files-to-android-emulator-sd-card/2808935#2808935)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Android Perspective (DDMS in Eclipse) to send the files to the SD Card.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2808935/373334) for more details.

Another option is to use the android debug bridge (ADB):

```
adb push myDirectory /sdcard/targetDir
```

Comment: one question here. is that possible copy all folder into `sdcard`.

Comment: yes, it copies the folder and all files inside the folder