# Is it possible to install an app on Eclipse AVD and not run it?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm testing a widget and I'd like to just install the new version without launching the main activity.  Is this possible?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the command line to achieve this. Use **adb install** path/your_application.apk. This will just install the app on your virtual device.
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Comment: The -r switch might be helpful to allow a reinstall of the apk. Else the command will fail if the app is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible, because as after the application is installed in your virtual device, the `onCreate` method immediately starts your application depending on the `main_activity` . Well, i think there might be some setup to disable the onCreate method from starting once the app is installed.

Answer (score 1):

just an addition- you can either install using command line or you can just build your apk using build and push it to your avd.

You can have a look at these two pages.
[first-](http://www.andrels.com/wp-en_US/2012/03/android-transferring-files-between-emulator-and-the-computer/) [Second-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808632/manually-put-files-to-android-emulator-sd-card) I hope it would help you.

Comment: Push it how, exactly?